# iPython Splitting

Tags: python

I have the following numbers in an array:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I want to create two new arrays with half of this array in each. I have attempted the following:

```
mid = len(a) / 2
a1 = (mid * ctypes.py_object)()
a2 = (mid * ctypes.py_object)()
for i in range(mid):
    a1[i] = a[i]
```

This works just fine for the first array. What I am having trouble with is the second array. I have tried:

```
for j in range(mid, len(a)):
    a2[j] = a[j]
```

I get an invalid index error. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`len(a) // 2` computes the floor of `len(a)` divided by 2. Problem is, if `a` has an odd length, say, 3, you create `a1` and `a2` as length 1 arrays (since `3 // 2 == 1`), so trying to put the remainder of `a` (2 elements) into `a2` (1 element) indexes out of bounds.

A simple solution is to define `a2` not as `mid` elements long, but as "remainder" elements long, e.g.:

```
mid = len(a) // 2
remainder = len(a) - mid
a1 = (mid * ctypes.py_object)()
a2 = (remainder * ctypes.py_object)()
```

You could inline the `remainder` computation if desired (`a2 = ((len(a) - mid) * ctypes.py_object)()`), I just split it out for clarity in the example.

An equivalent approach would be to simply round up for the `remainder` calculation, e.g. `remainder = (len(a) + 1) // 2`; the effect is the same, I'm just mentioning this as an alternative for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the arrays as below.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

mid = len(a) / 2
a1 = a[:mid]
a2 = a[mid:]
```

Comment: He said that he doesn't want to use index slicing I believe. He edited it though.